# Exception Handling and Error Logging limitation for ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, error-logging

We are using ReactJs version is 15.6.2

1. Error Boundaries library is not support, it is support only for React Version 16 and above.
2. try…catch method is not support for child components.

Logging Error into client side or server side is fine, the problem raise while try to catch the exceptions 
From components, child components and .js file exceptions.
Any idea or help for resolving this issue?

Comment: You mean you cannot do a "Try..Catch" in the render method of the child component?

Comment: Hi, pure try catch can't us in react js. if we want to use try catch we need to use some plugin. Please suggest any other methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React 15, you can use the precursor of `componentDidCatch` called [`unstable_handleError`](https://medium.com/@blairanderson/handle-react-errors-in-v15-4cedaae757d7).